# Setprogress for a progress bar across fragments android using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-progressbar, android-framelayout

I am an amateur to both, android studio and kotlin. I am implementing a scenario where I have some fragments, as and when we finish with one fragment, the progress is shown on the main layout. These fragments replace the main frame layout and switching from one fragment to next is done in the previous fragment using the `setonclicklistener`. However, the problem is that I am unable to see the update happening to the progressbar. By the way, I am not using any progress dialogue. All I need is to update the progress bar as I switch from one fragment to another. When I run the App, it doesn't crash but the update doesn't happen. The main_layout file as given below and the frame layout is replaced by the fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/parentmain_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"

style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:scaleY="2"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentmain_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/parentmain_progress">
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

One of the fragments where the progress is not updated:

```
class ParentChildInfoFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent_info_relation, container, false)

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    headerparentrelation_text?.text= arguments?.getString("name")
    parentmain_progress?.max=4
    parentmain_progress?.setProgress(3)
    val string = "Your Cild is a....\n Girl/Boy"
    specifying_relation_txt?.text = string

    relation_mom_image?.setImageResource(R.drawable.girl)
    relation_dad_image?.setImageResource(R.drawable.boy)

    val girlstring = "Girl"
    mom_txt?.text = girlstring

    val boystring = "Boy"
    dad_txt?.text=boystring

    nextbtn_parentrelation.setOnClickListener {
        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.parentmain_frame,ParentInfoFragment())?.commit()
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that ?

On this example I use the new package structure : `Androidx`

If you do not use it yet, simply change

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
```

by

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

You will find the code on this deposit :

https://github.com/Amadou19/Android-Multiple-fragment-with-progressBar---Kotlin.git

```
  /****************************/
    fragment1.xml
    /****************************/
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c15d5d">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="Fragment 1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Click Me"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    /****************************/
    Fragment1
    /****************************/
    class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

        interface Fragment1Listner {
            fun onClickFragment1()
        }

        var a1: Fragment1Listner? = null

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)

            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                a1?.onClickFragment1()
            }

            return view
        }
    }
    /****************************/
    fragment2.xml
    /****************************/
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#5d80c1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="Fragment 2"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Click Me"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    /****************************/
    Fragment2
    /****************************/
    class Fragment2 : Fragment() {

        interface Fragment2Listner {
            fun onClickFragment2()
        }

        var a2: Fragment2Listner? = null

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false)

            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                a2?.onClickFragment2()
            }

            return view    }

    }

    /****************************/
    fragment3.xml
    /****************************/
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fab049">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="Fragment 3"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    /****************************/
    Fragment3
    /****************************/
    class Fragment3 : Fragment() {


        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false)

            return view    }

    }


    /****************************/
    activity_main.xml
    /****************************/
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.amadoutirera.progressbar2.MainActivity">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    /****************************/
    MainActivity
    /****************************/
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Fragment1.Fragment1Listner, Fragment2.Fragment2Listner {
    lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar


        private lateinit var fragment1: Fragment1
        private lateinit var fragment2: Fragment2
        private lateinit var fragment3: Fragment3


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            /*------------------------------------------*/
            progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_bar)
            progressBar.max = 90
            progressBar.progress = 30
            /*------------------------------------------*/
            fragment1 = Fragment1()
            fragment2 = Fragment2()
            fragment3 = Fragment3()
            /*------------------------------------------*/
            fragment1.a1 = this
            fragment2.a2 = this
            /*------------------------------------------*/
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment1)
                    .commit()
        }
        /*--------------- Onclik interface implementation -------------------*/
        override fun onClickFragment1() {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment2)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()

            progressBar.incrementProgressBy(30)

        }

        override fun onClickFragment2() {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment3)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
            progressBar.incrementProgressBy(30)

        }

        /*------------------------------------------*/
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed()
            if(progressBar.progress ==60 || progressBar.progress ==90) progressBar.incrementProgressBy(-30)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to Put your code in onCreateView() method.
Hope it works!!

Comment: are you replacing your fragment or adding fragment ??
can you please share your code snippet when you are replacing fragment ?

Comment: The replacing code snippet has also been posted. Its inside the setonclicklistener.

Comment: as i see your progressbar is in activity and when you replace your fragment from activity at that time you can update the progressbar. NO need to write code in your fragment.

Comment: I am replacing fragments in current fragment itself. I am not doing the replacing action in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
parentmain_progress?.post({
        parentmain_progress?.progress = 3
})
```

instead of `parentmain_progress?.setProgress(3)`

Comment: It doesn't work in both onviewcreated and oncreateview. The progress bar isn't updated.